# kubernetes trigger when pod upgrade turns Running?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

**I wanna have a trigger when I make a deployment of my React application, and my pod is finally `running`**

I need this Kubernetes trigger, in order to launch another pod which is gonna copy/past the static files for another pod specific just made for static files. (I wanna do this to keep the old `bundle.js` if ever users on the application are still surfing with old bundles, this way I'll be able to make a fat PWA)

I don't wanna have to wait myself the end of the deployment (6 minutes of docker building enough to take a cup of tea)

When my React app is `Running` => My goal is to start a pod which is gonna make a `kubectl` command from inside the cluster and kill himself afterwards

The command from inside the pod is gonna be a simple copy/past `kubectl cp fresh-new-deployment/static pod-just-for-static-files/var/www`

Everything is working fine in local, I just need the Kubernetes trigger ;)

I don't want to make a kubernetes CRON for this (or maybe this is the only way), or an every minute CRON ? what you recommend ?

Thanks I already typed in google `kubernetes trigger when pod running` there was nothing interesting.

Answer (score 4):

Ideally you should use `init-containers` pattern described here https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/pods/init-containers/

https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/configure-pod-initialization/

Here are some ideas for how to use init containers:

*Wait for a Service to be created, using a shell one-line command like:*

```
for i in {1..100}; do sleep 1; if dig myservice; then exit 0; fi; done; exit 1
```

*Register this Pod with a remote server from the downward API with a command like:*

```
curl -X POST http://$MANAGEMENT_SERVICE_HOST:$MANAGEMENT_SERVICE_PORT/register -d 'instance=$(<POD_NAME>)&ip=$(<POD_IP>)'
```

*Wait for some time before starting the app container with a command like*

```
sleep 60
```

Comment: Many thanks for these guidelines. It looks like it's gonna work ;) I will be able to keep the old bundle.js for sometimes in cache. Cheers

Comment: Nice . I m glad I could help

Answer (score 0):

You know what, I am too lazy at doing all this mess.

I am gonna make for each deployment a

```
kubectl cp pod-react:/dist/client/static ./Desktop
kubectl cp ./Desktop pod-static-nginx:/static
```

I am not a devops ;)